# Failed to fetch package when install ros-indigo-uvc-camera

Tags: ubuntu, ros, apt

I am running ROS Indigo in Nvidia Tegra K1. After installed ROS, I want to install uvc camera but faced error.

> Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main libv4l2rds0
>   armhf 1.0.1-1   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80] Err
>   http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main
>   ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers armhf
>   1.11.10-0trusty-20160629-210550-0700   Connection failed [IP: 64.50.233.100 80] E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/v/v4l-utils/libv4l2rds0_1.0.1-1_armhf.deb
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers_1.11.10-0trusty-20160629-210550-0700_armhf.deb
>   Connection failed [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-missing?

I suspect it is due to the source list and here is my source list.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty universe
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-backports main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-backports main restricted

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security universe
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the links are working fine for me can you make sure you have proper internet connection on that machine / for example try one of the links :

wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers_1.11.10-0trusty-20160629-210550-0700_armhf.deb

if it will not work it suggest some network related problem with your machine